# How to update the Expandable listview when new item is added to it

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have created an expandable listview which loads data from sqlite when the listview reaches bottom.It again loads another set of data from sqlite using async task.In this the header gets updated with the new datas but the child view for the latest data is empty can anyone tell me how to update/refresh the expandable list adapter when new data's get loaded.

Adapter:

```
public class DaybookExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
String updatedate = "";
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<Daybooklist>> _listDataChild;
private DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
boolean isListScrolling;

public DaybookExpandableAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                HashMap<String, List<Daybooklist>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    /*final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    final String childtime = (String) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);*/
    Daybooklist daybooklist = (Daybooklist) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.model_daybook_listitem, null);
    }

    TextView txtname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_name);
    TextView txttime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_time);
    TextView day_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_name);
    TextView day_description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_description);
    TextView day_type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_type);
    TextView day_amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_amount);
    TextView day_usertype = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_usertype);
    TextView day_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_time);
    ImageView day_check = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_doneall);
    TextView daybook_location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_location);


    txtname.setText(daybooklist.getName());
    txttime.setText(daybooklist.getCtime());
    databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(_context);
    if (daybooklist.getUsertype() != null && !daybooklist.getUsertype().isEmpty()) {
        if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer") | daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("singleworker") | daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("groupworker") | daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("payvehicle")) {
            if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer")) {
                day_name.setText(daybooklist.getName());
                day_description.setText(daybooklist.getDescription());
                String mobno = daybooklist.getMobileno();
                Log.e("mobno", mobno);
                String locat = String.valueOf(databaseHandler.getfarmerlocation(mobno));
                locat = locat.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
                Log.e("farmerlocation", locat);
                daybook_location.setText(locat);
                day_type.setText(daybooklist.getType());
                if (daybooklist.getName() != null && daybooklist.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (daybooklist.getDescription() != null && daybooklist.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }

                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + daybooklist.getExtraamt());
                if (daybooklist.getAmountout().startsWith("0.0") | daybooklist.getAmountout().startsWith("0")) {
                    //     day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    Log.e("Amountout", daybooklist.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    //    day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.album_title));
                    Log.e("Amountout", daybooklist.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                day_time.setText(daybooklist.getCtime());
            } else {
                day_name.setText(daybooklist.getName());
                day_description.setText(daybooklist.getDescription());
                daybook_location.setText(daybooklist.getType());
                day_type.setText(daybooklist.getType());
                if (daybooklist.getName() != null && daybooklist.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (daybooklist.getDescription() != null && daybooklist.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }

                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + daybooklist.getExtraamt());
                if (daybooklist.getAmountout().startsWith("0.0") | daybooklist.getAmountout().startsWith("0")) {
                    //  day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    Log.e("Amountout", daybooklist.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    //  day_amount.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.album_title));
                    Log.e("Amountout", daybooklist.getAmountout());
                    day_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                day_time.setText(daybooklist.getCtime());
            }


        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer") | daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("workeradvance") | daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("kgroupadvance") | daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("otherexpense") | daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("vehicle")) {
            if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer")) {
                day_name.setText(daybooklist.getName());
                day_description.setText(daybooklist.getDescription());
                day_type.setText(daybooklist.getType());
                String mobno = daybooklist.getMobileno();
                Log.e("mobno", mobno);
                String locat = String.valueOf(databaseHandler.getfarmerlocation(mobno));
                locat = locat.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
                Log.e("farmerlocation", locat);
                daybook_location.setText(locat);
                if (daybooklist.getName() != null && daybooklist.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (daybooklist.getDescription() != null && daybooklist.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }
                Log.e("amountout", daybooklist.getAmountout());
                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + daybooklist.getAmountout());
                day_time.setText(daybooklist.getCtime());
            } else {
                day_name.setText(daybooklist.getName());
                day_description.setText(daybooklist.getType());
                day_type.setText(daybooklist.getType());
                daybook_location.setText(daybooklist.getDescription());
                if (daybooklist.getName() != null && daybooklist.getName().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_name.setText(" ");
                } else if (daybooklist.getDescription() != null && daybooklist.getDescription().startsWith("no")) {
                    day_description.setText(" ");
                }
                Log.e("amountout", daybooklist.getAmountout());
                day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + daybooklist.getAmountout());
                day_time.setText(daybooklist.getCtime());
            }


        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("buyer")) {
            day_name.setText(daybooklist.getName());
            day_description.setText(daybooklist.getDescription());
            day_amount.setText("\u20B9" + daybooklist.getAmountin());
            day_type.setText(" ");
            day_time.setText(daybooklist.getCtime());
            daybook_location.setText(daybooklist.getType());
        }
        if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("farmer")) {
            day_usertype.setText("F");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_farmer);
        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("advancefarmer")) {
            day_usertype.setText("FA");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_farmer);
        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("singleworker")) {
            day_usertype.setText("W");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("workeradvance")) {
            day_usertype.setText("WA");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("groupworker")) {
            day_usertype.setText("G");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("kgroupadvance")) {
            day_usertype.setText("GA");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("otherexpense")) {
            day_usertype.setText("E");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_otherexpense);
        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("vehicle")) {
            day_usertype.setText("V");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_vehicle);
        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("gsalary")) {
            day_usertype.setText("GS");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("isalary")) {
            day_usertype.setText("WS");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_worker);
        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("payvehicle")) {
            day_usertype.setText("VP");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_vehicle);
        } else if (daybooklist.getUsertype().startsWith("buyer")) {
            day_usertype.setText("B");
            day_usertype.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_buyer);
        }
    }


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.model_daybook_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.tv_daybook_date);
    final ImageView img_pdg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_printpdf);

    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    String strDate = headerTitle;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyyyy");
    try {
        Date varDate = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        updatedate = dateFormat.format(varDate);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    img_pdg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    img_pdg.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(_context, R.color.colorAccent));

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    img_pdg.clearColorFilter();
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            _context);

                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.daybookreport) + headerTitle)
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, close
                                    // current activity
                                    Intent pdfreport = new Intent(_context, Activity_Daybookpdf.class);
                                    pdfreport.putExtra("date", updatedate);
                                    _context.startActivity(pdfreport);
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                                    img_pdg.clearColorFilter();
                                    dialog.cancel();

                                }
                            });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();
                    Button nbutton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                    nbutton.setTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                    Button pbutton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                    pbutton.setBackgroundColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                    pbutton.setPadding(0, 10, 10, 0);
                    pbutton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    break;
            }
            return true;


        }
    });
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            img_pdg.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(_context, R.color.colorAccent));
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    _context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.daybookreport) + headerTitle)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, close
                            // current activity
                            Intent pdfreport = new Intent(_context, Activity_Daybookpdf.class);
                            pdfreport.putExtra("date", updatedate);
                            _context.startActivity(pdfreport);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            img_pdg.clearColorFilter();
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
            Button nbutton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            nbutton.setTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            Button pbutton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            pbutton.setBackgroundColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            pbutton.setPadding(0, 10, 10, 0);
            pbutton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public void setTransactionList(List<String> newList, HashMap<String, List<Daybooklist>> childlist) {

    _listDataHeader.clear();
    _listDataChild.clear();
    _listDataHeader = newList;
    _listDataChild = childlist;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setVTransactionList(List<String> newList) {
    _listDataHeader = newList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void isScrolling(boolean isScroll) {
    isListScrolling = isScroll;
    Log.e("scrollcheck", String.valueOf(isListScrolling));
}
```

}

Async task:

```
 class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Daybooklist daybooklist = new Daybooklist();
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... olimits) {
        String limits = null;
        kickstart = 2;
        olimit=20;
        Log.e("kickcheck", String.valueOf(kickstart));
        loadingMore = true;
        try {
            limits = olimits[0];
            Log.e("limitscheck",limits);
            daybooks = new ArrayList<Daybook>();
            daybooks = databaseHandler.getAlldaybookentriesdatewise(olimit);
            daybooklists = new ArrayList<Daybooklist>();


            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<Daybooklist>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < daybooks.size(); i++) {
                String date = daybooks.get(i).getDate();
                if (date != null) {
                    String s = date;
                    String[] spiliter = s.split("-");
                    String year = spiliter[0];
                    String month = spiliter[1];
                    String dates = spiliter[2];
                    if (month.startsWith("01")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Jan" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("02")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Feb" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("03")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Mar" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("04")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Apr" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("05")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "May" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("06")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Jun" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("07")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Jul" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("08")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Aug" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("09")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Sep" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("10")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Oct" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("11")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Nov" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    } else if (month.startsWith("12")) {
                        disorderedlist = dates + "Dec" + year;
                        disorderedlist = disorderedlist.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    }
                    listDataHeader.add(disorderedlist);
                }

                chid = new ArrayList<Daybooklist>();
                daybooklists = databaseHandler.getAllDaywisedaybookdetails(date);
                for (int j = 0; j < daybooklists.size(); j++) {


                    String name = daybooklists.get(j).getName();
                    String desc = daybooklists.get(j).getDescription();
                    String type = daybooklists.get(j).getType();
                    String usertype = daybooklists.get(j).getUsertype();
                    String amtin = daybooklists.get(j).getAmountin();
                    String amtout = daybooklists.get(j).getAmountout();
                    String extamt = daybooklists.get(j).getExtraamt();
                    String mobno = daybooklists.get(j).getMobileno();
                    String dates = daybooklists.get(j).getSdate();
                    String time = daybooklists.get(j).getCtime();


                    if (name != null) {
                        chid.add(new Daybooklist(name, desc, type, usertype, amtin, amtout, extamt, mobno, dates, time));

                    }

                }


                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), chid);


            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return disorderedlist;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String disorderedlist) {
       // listAdapter = new DaybookExpandableAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

          listAdapter.setTransactionList(listDataHeader,listDataChild);
        loadingMore = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        // Notify the loading more operation has finished
        loadingMore = false;
    }
}
```

Adapter notify:

```
  public void setTransactionList(List<String> newList, HashMap<String, List<Daybooklist>> childlist) {

    _listDataHeader.clear();
    _listDataChild.clear();
    _listDataHeader = newList;
    _listDataChild = childlist;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Database:

```
  public ArrayList<Daybook> getAlldaybookentriesdatewise(int s) {
    ArrayList<Daybook> daybookDetails = new ArrayList<Daybook>();
    String selectquery = "SELECT date,IFNULL(SUM(amountin),0) as amountin,IFNULL(SUM(amountout),0) as amountout,daybookusertype FROM daybookdetails GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date) ORDER BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date) DESC LIMIT " + s + "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectquery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Daybook daybookentries = new Daybook();
            daybookentries.setDate(cursor.getString(0));
            daybookentries.setCashin(cursor.getString(1));
            daybookentries.setCashout(cursor.getString(2));
            daybookDetails.add(daybookentries);


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return daybookDetails;
}
```

I have already tried using notifydatasetchanged but it didn't works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the adapter in the View, inside the `onPostExecute()` method:

```java
protected void onPostExecute(String disorderedlist) {
    listAdapter = new DaybookExpandableAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listAdapter.setTransactionList(listDataHeader,listDataChild);
    loadingMore = false;
}
```